# How to click on this javascript element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th colspan="9">
<span id="pageText">
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:setData(2,true)"><</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:setData(2,false)">></a>
</span>
</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this, but it does not work:
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('>').click()");

i want to click on ">" link.

Comment: Please provide html of the snippet u posted..

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no id `>`. For id attached to an element see what is contained in the **id** attribute of the element, what u provided is the **innerHTML or TextContent** of the element.
Secondly you can achieve it using webdriver functions also as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='pageText']/a[contains(.,'>')]")).click();
```